# Convert SecKeyRef to EC_KEY in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, security, key-pair

I'm creating CSR from openSSL but due to OpenSSL isn't storing keys in secure enclave so I chooses objective C to create key pair (private key and public key) in secure enclave and send to OpenSSL for X509 certificate. I get successfully public key in NSData and then convert `const unsigned char * bitsOfKeyDataPublicKey = (unsigned char *) [publicKey bytes];` and then create public key `EC_KEY*_ec_keyPublic = d2i_EC_PUBKEY(NULL,&bitsOfKeyDataPublicKey, publicKeyLegnth);`. But For Private key we get `SecKeyRef` from objective c so for creation `EC_Key` how can we convert private key or is this any way to convert or use private key ?
Looking for response.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change private key from `SecKeyRef` to `NSData`

Example:

```
- (NSData *)getPrivateKeyBits {
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    NSData * privateKeyBits = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary * queryPrivateKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Set the public key query dictionary.

    [queryPrivateKey setObject:(id)kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:_privateTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeEC forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecReturnData];

    // Get the key bits.
    sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPrivateKey, (void *)&privateKeyBits);

    if (sanityCheck != noErr) {
        privateKeyBits = nil;
    }
    else if (sanityCheck == errSecItemNotFound) {
        privateKeyBits = nil;
    }

    return privateKeyBits;
}
```

Don't forget to use the `_privateTag` used for generating private key

now you can use:

```
const unsigned char *bitsOfKeyDataPrivateKey = (unsigned char *) [[self getPrivateKeyBits] bytes];
EC_KEY *_ec_keyPrivate = d2i_EC_PUBKEY(NULL,&bitsOfKeyDataPrivateKey, privateKeyLegnth);
```

Comment: What has to give in "privateKeyLegnth"?

Comment: The first part of this answer (how to export the key) is correct, but the exported key is not compatible with `d2i_EC_PUBKEY`. See: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/84684#84684

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `d2i_PrivateKey_bio` for the private key?